# How to fetch cabin name using cabinfk_id in yii?

Tags: yii

I have two tables 
ie.
1)cabins(id,cabinname,status)
 where in cabins table id is a primary key[.][1]

2)tables(id,cabinfk_id,tablename,status)
here cabinfk_id is a reference key of cabins table id.

here in above form when i create new tables where in a single cabin there are many tables so as i enter three tables in mercury-cabin

here i saved it it successfully get saved but in view file of table in a list threre appers table name cabin name and status

**My Question is in cabin name column i want cabin name as mercury instead of cabin id shown as 28 28 28**  in fig 2

## Model-code of tables

----------------------------start------------------------------

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

```
**
 * This is the model class for table "tables".
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $tablename
 * @property int $cabinfk_id
 * @property int $status 1=active, 0=inactive
 *
 * @property Orders[] $orders
 * @property Cabins $cabinfk
 */
class Tables extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tables';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['tablename', 'cabinfk_id', 'status'], 'required'],
            [['cabinfk_id', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['tablename'], 'string', 'max' => 40],
            [['cabinfk_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Cabins::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['cabinfk_id' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
            'tablename' => Yii::t('app', 'Tablename'),
            // 'cabinfk_id' => Yii::t('app', 'Cabinfk ID'),
            'cabinfk_id' => Yii::t('app', 'Cabin Name'),
            'status' => Yii::t('app', 'Status'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getOrders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Orders::className(), ['tablefk_id' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCabinfk()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Cabins::className(), ['id' => 'cabinfk_id']);

    }
}
```

------------------------end-----------------------------

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gridView you can set like this:

```
   [
     'attribute' => 'cabinfk_id',
     'value' => 'cabinfk.name'
     ],
```

If you have details view:

```
 [
         'attribute' => 'cabinfk_id',
         'value' => $model->cabinfk->name,

      ],
```